# Submit button not validating

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a submit button to take me to the next page when the input is `milk`. Here's what I've tried so far

```
package com.example.ephraimcohen.prestwichlanguageschool;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activitytwomilk2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText Word;
    private TextView TryAgain;
    private Button Submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activitytwomilk2);

        Word = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etword);
        TryAgain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtryagian);
        Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);

        TryAgain.setText(" ");

        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validate(Word.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void validate(String userWord){
        if((userWord.equals ("milk"))){
            Intent intent = new Intent(activitytwomilk2.this, activitytwomilkcorrect.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }else{

            TryAgain.setText(" " + "Try again");
            }
        }`
```

Under that, there is another button which just goes to the home screen. That button is working properly and taking me to the homepage.

Comment: Did you register the `activitytwomilkcorrect` activity in the manifest? Do you reach the `startActivity()` line when debugging?

Comment: the `activitytwomilkcorrect` is registered on the manifest. How do you debug the app, and what am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use == instead of equals in your condition

```
    if(userWord=="milk"){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activitytwomilk2.this, activitytwomilkcorrect.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        TryAgain.setText(" " + "Try again");
        }
    }`
```

Comment: your code just works fine .. try to rebuild your project

Comment: I've tried rebuilding and it has not helped. In the Logcat, this comes up when I press the button. 02-24 23:08:31.257 572-2710/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only